# Enable TextField on basis of other TextField Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

There are two text fields (with auto-complete feature):

```
<label for="name">Customer:</label>
<input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" value=""  />
<input type="hidden" id="customer-id" />
<p id="customer-description"></p>


<label for="name">Store:</label>
<input type="text" name="store" id="store" value=""  disabled="true" />
<input type="hidden" id="store-id" />
<p id="store-description"></p>
```

As you can see, initially I disabled second textfield. What I want is when user is done selecting item from customer textbox, the store textbox should get enabled.
This is what i tried but it does not enable store field:

```
$(function() {
    $('#customer').autocomplete({
        source: "./SearchCustomer.php?term="+document.getElementById("customer").value,
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#customer-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };
    $("#store").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
});
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by _it is not working_?

Comment: I mean the store field is not getting enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#customer').autocomplete({
        source: "./SearchCustomer.php?term="+document.getElementById("customer").value,
        minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#customer-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $("#store").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" ).append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `$('#store').prop('disabled', false).focus();` to your select function:

```
select: function(ev, ui) {
    $( "#customer" ).val( ui.item.label );
    $( "#customer-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $( "#store" ).prop( 'disabled', false ).focus();
    return false;
}
```

So, when an autocomplete item is selected, set the disabled property of `#store` to false, and give the element focus.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMPdg/)